# Activate the keys Windows + H programatically

Tags: windows, speech-recognition, dictation

I want to activate Windows + H (dictation for speech recognition) for my apps. How can I do it, please?

Finally, thanks you so much for your advice.

I dont know how to activate Windows + H

Answer (score 0):

You just have to press the Windows key on your keyboard and the letter H (Windows+H) **while focused on any input box**. The first time you trigger it takes some time to initialize it and you should see something like this:

[image]

The text here was added with that feature:
test 12 3

Here is a gif with the process:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my question here is how can I activate those compose keys by programmation, but not through a manual gesture.

Comment: Yeah, the post does not mention that you need to do it programmatically. Maybe by using something like Autohotkey to trigger it? More details in the description will help answer the question better.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I wish you a nice day.